# Javascript array multiple instances created

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am making a search function for a glossary (a set of `div`s with class `searchable`). When the search term is first processed I instantiate the array by

```
const foundset =  [];
```

The search is then carried out by this function which identifies entries containing the search string

```
$(".searchable").each(function(){
  if($(this).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1) {
    // Only unique ids
    if ( ! foundset.includes($(this).parent('.entry').attr('id')) ) {
       foundset.push($(this).parent('.entry').attr('id'));
    }
  }
});
```

Which gives me an array of divs that contain my search string.

Then using a button (the handler is within the handler for the original search so I can access the array `foundset` set up in the parent handler) I can step through the divs, scrolling to each one.

```
$('#results button').on('click', function () {
   if (foundset.length > 0) {
     foundset.shift();
     console.log (foundset);
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#" + foundset[0]).offset().top - 200
       }, 1000);
     } else {
     $('#results').hide();
     $('#results .search-term').text('');
     $('#results .count').text('');
   }
});
```

What I have found is that when I make a second search the original array still exists, ie I appear to have 2 arrays that have the name `foundset`.  I can see them in the console when I run the button handler.

I assume that the button handler is storing the original array and is being passed a second instance when the second search is called. How do I reset the state to run a second search?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

I have to apologise but outlining my question produced a thought trail that has led me to the answer.

The button was still doing its stuff for the first search when the second search was started so it is necessary to destroy that handler before calling again.

```
 $('#results button').off();
```

Comment: I wish I understood this better.